# How do I compare the prompt response to my variable?

Tags: javascript, function, variables, if-statement, prompt

The user is supposed to enter one of several given names into the prompt box. If their response is not one of the given names, they are told that that is not a valid response. If they do, however, then they are told who they have selected. The issue is, no matter what I type in, it keeps saying that it's an invalid name. Any Advice how to fix this?

```
 <html>
<body bgcolor = "firebrick">
    <title>Dinner Plans</title>
    <center><h1><b> Dinner Plans</h1>
        <p> Guests to Pick From:</p></b>
        <p> Jane, Lisa, Taylor, Chris, Alyssa, Will and Jessica </p>
       <button onclick="Invites()">Click To Invite</button>
  <div id = "Coming"></div>
<script>
function Invites() {
var txt;
var person = prompt("Who is Coming For Dinner?", "Enter Names Here");
if (person == null || person != guest) {
    txt = "Not A Valid Guest.";
} 
else {
    txt = "Your Invited Guests Are:" + person;
}
document.getElementById("Coming").innerHTML = txt;
}

function guest ( slices , toppings ) {
  this.numSlices = slices;
  this.numToppings = toppings; 
}
var Jane = new guest( 2, "Mushroom", "Onions", "Peppers", "Olives");
var Lisa = new guest(3, "Pepperoni", "Ham", "Pineapple");
var Taylor = new guest(3, "Extra Cheese", "Pepperoni", "Sausage", "Bacon");
var Chris = new guest(2, "Mushroom", "Sausage", "Bacon", "Ham", "Onion", "Peppers");
var Alyssa = new guest(1, " Pepperoni", "Bacon");
var Will = new guest(2, "Extra Cheese", "Sausage", "Bacon", "Onion", "Peppers", "Olives");
var Jessica = new guest(2, "Pepperoni", "Bacon", "Ham", "Pineapple", "Onion", "Peppers");

if (Invites == null || Invites == "") {
    txt = " You invited zero guests, you have a pizza all to yourself!";
} else { 
    txt = " You Invited:" + Invites; 
}

        </script>
```

Comment: what is your guest ? person != guest as guest is not a value its not working

Comment: You haven't declared the `guest` variable

Comment: the second parameter to guest should probably be an array of toppings, right now it's just looking at the first topping you send.  if you `console.log(Jane.numToppings)` you will get "Mushroom".

Comment: Also just throwing this out there, you could use a dropdown with a list of your guests.

Comment: `guest` **is** declared. It is a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<script>
function Invites() {
    var txt;
    var guestArray = [
        "Jane",
        "Lisa",
        "Taylor",
        "Chris",
        "Alyssa",
        "Will",
        "Jessica"
    ];

    var person = prompt("Who is Coming For Dinner?", "Enter Names Here");
    if (person == null || guestArray.indexOf(person) === -1) {
        txt = "Not A Valid Guest.";
    } 
    else {
        txt = "Your Invited Guests Are:" + person;
    }

    document.getElementById("Coming").innerHTML = txt;
}

function guest ( slices , toppings ) {
    this.numSlices = slices;
    this.numToppings = toppings; 
}

var Jane = new guest( 2, "Mushroom", "Onions", "Peppers", "Olives");
var Lisa = new guest(3, "Pepperoni", "Ham", "Pineapple");
var Taylor = new guest(3, "Extra Cheese", "Pepperoni", "Sausage", "Bacon");
var Chris = new guest(2, "Mushroom", "Sausage", "Bacon", "Ham", "Onion", "Peppers");
var Alyssa = new guest(1, " Pepperoni", "Bacon");
var Will = new guest(2, "Extra Cheese", "Sausage", "Bacon", "Onion", "Peppers", "Olives");
var Jessica = new guest(2, "Pepperoni", "Bacon", "Ham", "Pineapple", "Onion", "Peppers");

if (Invites == null || Invites == "") {
    txt = " You invited zero guests, you have a pizza all to yourself!";
} else { 
    txt = " You Invited:" + Invites; 
}

</script>


<title>Dinner Plans</title>
<center><h1><b> Dinner Plans</h1>
<p> Guests to Pick From:</p></b>
<p> Jane, Lisa, Taylor, Chris, Alyssa, Will and Jessica </p>
<button onclick="Invites()">Click To Invite</button>
<div id = "Coming"></div>
```

So there are following problems with your code:

- guest is constructor function. not a value(name of the guest) you are
  expecting.
- To compare the name filled in the prompt, you need list    of valid
  names.
- For that you can use an array of names(guestArray here).
- I have used indexOf function which is available on Array instances in
  javascript. It returns -1 when no match is found in
           array or index of the element if match is there.

Comment: You're answer is helpful, but I must point out a couple of ways to improve it. `guest` is declared - it's a function. Also, you may want to explain the other changes you made to the code (i.e. `var guestArray` and `guestArray.indexOf(person) === -1`). Depending on how much the asker knows about programming, it may be instructive to describe why using your approach is an improvement over the asker's approach.

Comment: Thank You so much, now that you explained it I can see where I went wrong.